# Dynamics 365 Authentication

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, azure-active-directory

Microsoft Dynamics 365 supports three security models for authentication: Claims-based authentication, Active Directory authentication, and OAuth 2.0.

I've managed to implement the Active Directory authentication which is based on Oath2.0. What might be the difference between Active Directory authentication and Oath 2.0 and How can I configure OAuth 2.0 security for Dynamics 365. I don't have so much knowledge about Oath or Active Directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my understanding, one benefit of using OAuth is that your application can support multi-factor authentication.

You can refer the links below about the detail between OAuth and Active Directory and claims-based authentication:

[Connect to Microsoft Dynamics 365 web services using OAuth](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327838.aspx)

[Active Directory and claims-based authentication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334502.aspx)

What did you mean OAuth 2.0 security for Dynamics 365?

Comment: Hei Fei Xue, In the first link it says: // Authenticate the registered application with Azure Active Directory although the title "is Microsoft Dynamics 365 web services using OAuth" - so I don't understand this part: "Active Directory authentication, and OAuth 2.0". Is that authentication Active Directory authentication or Oath2.0. It's Oath authentication and the factor is Active Directory?

Comment: The Azure Active Directory supports OAuth 2.0 protocol. When we acquire the access token to access the resource from Azure AD, we are interact with Azure AD through OAuth 2.0 protocol. But the Active Directory authentication and claims-based authentication for Dynamics 365 is different. Claims-based authentication is a set of WS-* standards describing the use of a Security Assertion Markup Language (SAML) token. You can get the detail about this from the second link in the orignal post.

Comment: Ok so Azure AD and AD are different things :). Well, it's more clear for me now.